# A kind of pertubation of laplacian is an Fredholm operator

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, bifurcation, variational-analysis

Let $U, V$ be Banach spaces and $L(U,V)$ be the space of bounded linear operators from $U$ to $V$. An operator $T \in L(U,V)$ is said to be a Fredholm operator if dim $N(T) < +\infty$ and $\mathrm{codim} R(T) < +\infty$. In this case, we define the index of a Fredholm operator $T$ as the integer
$$
\mathrm{ind}(T) = \mathrm{dim} N(T) - \mathrm{codim} R(T).
$$
Denote by $\mathrm{Fred}_0 (U,V)$ the set of the Fredholm operators with index zero from $U$ to $V$.

Given $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, consider the operator
$$T := -\Delta - \lambda I : C^{2}(\Omega) \rightarrow C(\overline{\Omega})$$
I'm trying to prove that $T$ is a Fredholm operator with $\mathrm{ind}(T) = 0$, for all $\lambda$. I already know that the operator $-\Delta : C^{2}(\Omega) \rightarrow C(\overline{\Omega})$ is in $\mathrm{Fred}_0(C^{2}, C)$, since its kernel is trivial by maximum principle and is surjective by Lax Milgram theorem and regularity theory. In addition, I know that $\mathrm{Fred}_0(U,V)$ is an open subset of $L(U,V)$. So, as $-\Delta \in \mathrm{Fred}_0(C^{2}, C)$, for small values of $\lambda$, $-\Delta - \lambda I$ is in a ball centered in $-\Delta$ which is contained in $\mathrm{Fred}_0(C^{2}, C)$. I don't know if there's another justification to conclude this with arbitrary values of $\lambda$.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Depending on your context, etc., it may be confusing to attempt to think of any perturbation of a Laplacian as being Fredholm, since Laplacians are essentially never bounded, and all the discussion of Fredholm operators I've seen assumes they're bounded/continuous. Conceivably there's "something new" in this line, but... I have to ask about your awareness of that convention...

Comment: Any new information would be very usefull for me.

Comment: In happy situations, the _resolvent_ of a Laplacian-like operator can be Fredholm. Is that conceivably your context? Would your eventual purposes be served by such a result... for bounded $\Omega$ with fairly smooth boundary, for example? That would be a fairly typical scenario in which things work well.

Comment: I will say more about my problem. I have an operator like $F: \mathbb{R} \times C^{2}(\Omega) \rightarrow C(\Omega)$ given by $F(\lambda, u) = -\Delta u - \lambda u - b(x) u^{p}$. Its derivative in $u$ variable in the point $(\lambda, 0)$ is $D_{u} F(\lambda, 0)\xi = \Delta \xi - \lambda \xi$. In bifurcation theory, its important the information that $D_{u} F(\lambda, 0)$ is not a bijection. If I had $D_{u} F(\lambda, 0) \in \text{Fred}_0(C^2,C)$, there's an equivalence which says that $D_{u} F(\lambda, 0)$ is not a bijection if $\text{dim}(N(D_{u} F(\lambda, 0))) \neq 0$.

Comment: I'm confused by how the $u$-derivative of $u^p$ disappears... but non-linear equations are outside my expertise...

Comment: No problem dear Paul, I thank you for your attention.